# JavaFX TableView rectangle between row and scrollbar

Tags: javafx

I have an issue with styling my TableView, because when I open new window with TableView it has something like on the picture below:

[image]

I don't know what causes it. When I click on another row in the table it's gone:

[image]

I also attach my CSS for table-view below:

```
.table-view{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color-navyBlue;
}

.table-view .filler{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color-navyBlue;
}

.table-view:focused{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color-navyBlue;
}

.table-view .column-header-background{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color-navyBlue;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-color-navyBlue;
}

.table-view .column-header-background .label{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color-darkGray;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-color-orange;
}

.table-view .column-header {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color-darkGray;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-color-navyBlue;
}

.table-view .table-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-color-lightGray;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-color-navyBlue;
}

.table-view .table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color-navyBlue, -fx-color-darkGray;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: -fx-color-navyBlue;
}

.table-view .table-row-cell:selected * {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color-orange;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-color-navyBlue;
}
```

Also my TableView Column Resize Policy is constrained-resize and maybe it causes it? But when it's unconstrained-resize it looks worse because of additional "empty" column like below:

[image]

Any tip how to get rid of it on window load?

Comment: Which javafx  version are you using? I have worked a lot with TableViews in javafx-8 and basically had to create a lot of 'hacky' workarounds to make it work reliable. Basically there are 2 stages of layout where only the first one is excuted on when initially shown, and after that only an active update would cause the second stage to be activated. What I did in the end is install a hook to resize the Tableview (via `Platform#runLater`) to force trigger the second stage, to get at least a reliable layout behavior. Not sure if that helps in any way, but AFAIK there is no solid workaround

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @kleopatra I wrote less because I thought it's kinda styling issue with css and I didn't want to write whole code because its pretty large and I use fxml to create view so my post would have too much code for this "simple" issue.

Comment: @n247s I'm using javafx 8. Thx for advice. I'll try to fix it somehow.

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you ;)

Comment: The reason she's asking for a MCVE is that if everyone on here is testing it and one finds a solution they can post otherwise it is just people taking guesses at what could be wrong.  Also you don't have to post the whole fxml just the part with a table in a container and a simple main class to start it

Answer (score 0):

I did what I could to get make this runnable so css doesnt look good because I was using the one from the question but had to make some edits to get it to work. If you uncomment the one line it gets rid of the third column I know you said you set it to resize I cannot replicate the issue your having if you take this modify it so you get the issue and post it I may be able to help otherwise probably not I would check where you set the `table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);` and make sure its executing correctly if you do it in fxml try setting it on initialization as well and see if that fixes the problem

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person("First", "Last"));

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
        //table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(event -> data.add(new Person("First","Last")));

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(table, addButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(vbox));
        scene.getStylesheets().add(String.valueOf(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("tableview.css")));

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) { firstName.set(fName); }

        public String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }

        public void setLastName(String fName) { lastName.set(fName); }
    }
}
```

tableview.css

```
.table-view{
    -fx-background-color: navy;
}

.table-view .filler{
    -fx-background-color:  navy;
}

.table-view:focused{
    -fx-background-color:  navy;
}

.table-view .column-header-background{
    -fx-background-color:  navy;
    -fx-border-color:  navy;
}

.table-view .column-header-background .label{
    -fx-background-color:  darkGray;
    -fx-text-fill:  orange;
}

.table-view .column-header {
    -fx-background-color:  darkGray;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-color:  navy;
}

.table-view .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill:  lightGray;
    -fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-color:  navy;
}


.table-view .table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color:  navy,  darkGray;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color:  navy;
}

.table-view .table-row-cell:selected * {
    -fx-background-color:  orange;
    -fx-text-fill:  navy;
}
```

Comment: "Also my TableView Column Resize Policy is constrained-resize ..."
As you see I already used this option. In code and in FXML file and both causes this thing on pic1. When you click on another row its gone (pic2). I just pointed with pic3 that when I use unconstrained-resize i have wide rectangle as additional column and when I switch to constrained-resize I have small rectangle which is very similar to this unconstrained-resize. Another thing I noticed is that it only happens when TableView needs scrollbar because of too much rows.

Comment: @kszulchs "As you see I already used this option. In code and in FXML" I cannot see as you have not posted your fxml or any code I cannot reproduce the error you are seeing i posted the code i used unless you can reproduce this with the code i posted i cannot help you